# Handling responses to multiple server request calls on Objective C

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am building an iOS matching app on Objective C where a user needs to continuously keep tapping on an image, and on every tap, a request (match.php) is called on the server to check if that image is found or not. If the image is present on the server, the server will send back a positive response, and if it is absent, it will not send any response.

If a positive response is received, the app shows a "Found" alert on the screen. After every tap, a new image is presented to the user.

My problem is, if I wait after tapping on one image, it works properly as I get the desired positive response form the php file for that particular image and then the alert may or may not be shown. But if I continue tapping on consecutive images, I don't get the old responses, and the alert does not popup even if it is present on the server. I get the response only from the last image on which I wait.

Is there any solution for this? Can I queue the responses so that for every server call, I get a response? Currently it seems on every tap the connection is overwritten and old ones get lost?

I am using NSURLConnection to make the server call, and the alert is shown in connectionDidFinishLoading depending upon the response I get. In the middle of these I am also using didReceiveData to append the data in the response and also didReceiveResponse to check response.

I know I should be using NSURLSession, but will it solve this problem, or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: After tap the image, disable the image's userInteraction, and send request to server. when server returns response, enable the image again.

Comment: I cannot restrict the user from tapping the next image nor can I wait till I get a response. Think of it like Tinder, where you keep swiping profiles, and if there is a match, you are shown a match screen, and if not the user keeps swiping.

Comment: With NSURLConnection, you need to manage the operation queue. But with NSURLSession runs on its own operationQueue. So NSURLSession should solve your problem, provided you're handling the response properly into the corresponding entry.

Comment: Are you keeping the NSURLConnection objects in an array so that they'll stick around?  What about their delegates?